# vim-latex ignores compile rule

Tags: vim, vim-latex

I just learned about LaTeX-Suite for vim and have a hard time setting up a compilation rule that invokes `make` to process my custom `Makefile`. The relevant section in my `.vimrc` reads

```
" vim-latex-suite setup:
filetype plugin on
filetype indent on
let g:tex_flavor='latex'
```

and `.vim/ftplugin/tex.vim` contains

```
" this is mostly a matter of taste. but LaTeX looks good with just a bit
" of indentation.
set sw=2
" TIP: if you write your \label's as \label{fig:something}, then if you
" type in \ref{fig: and press <C-n> you will automatically cycle through
" all the figure labels. Very useful!
set iskeyword+=:

" Compilation rules:
let g:Tex_DefaultTargetFormat = 'pdf'
let g:Tex_CompileRule_pdf = 'make $*.pdf'
```

If I omit the `let g:Tex_DefaultTargetFormat = 'pdf'`-line, `\ll` will build using `latex`, so the `DefaultTargetFormat` is treated correctly. But I can write into the `CompileRule` whatever I want, it will always produce the `GNU make` error `make: *** No rule to make target 'pdf'`.

The FAQ tells me to make sure, that `:set makeprg?` shows the same value as `:set Tex_CompileRule_dvi`, but it shows `makeprg=make "pdf"` instead. So LaTeX-Suite seems to be executing `make "pdf"`, ignoring my compilation rule entirely.

I tried `set makeprg=make\ %:r.pdf`, but it does not even change the output of `:set makeprg?`, leaving me with the very same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds like the expected behaviour due to `g:Tex_UseMakefile` taking its default value of `1`.  This leads vim-latex to override any `Tex_CompileRule_<fmt>` **if** a `makefile` is found, and to issue `g:Tex_DefaultTargetFormat` as the target to `make`, hence you're seeing `make "pdf"`.

With `let g:Tex_UseMakefile="0"`, the appropriate compile rule (which can still be a call to `make`) is followed even if a `makefile` is found.

Depending on the compilation rule it might be possible to configure within vim-latex using `g:Tex_FormatDependency_<fmt>` to indicate multiple compile rules and then take advantage of e.g. automatic multiple compilations to try and get cross-references right from a single `\ll` compilation call.

Comment: Thank you for that incredibly polite RTFM. In fact I recognized `g:Tex_UseMakefile`, but missed its default behaviour.
Using `g:Tex_FormatDependency_<fmt>` is not an option because I have a lot of additional scripts being executed (mainly plotting).